# Google Translate Using VBA - (Excel Macro) Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that the IT leader of my company gave me (he isnt here anymore), and we have been using it normally, but since we changed to office 2019 it stopped working, I was reviewing it and apparently it is something in objHTTP that is not returning a result, someone could help me to know why this happens and how could I solve it? I already tried to search in several places but as I mentioned this tool is already used by many people in my work and I need it to remain the same.

```
Sub TranslateCell()
'Traductor Ingles Español Usando Google Translate
    Dim getParam As String, trans As String, translateFrom As String, translateTo As String
'En translateFrom selecionaremos el idioma del cual traduciremos Ej. "en" = English
    translateFrom = "en"
'En translateTo selecionaremos el idioma que obtendremos Ej. "es" = Español
    translateTo = "es"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Dim r As Range, cell As Range
    Set cell = Selection
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        getParam = ConvertToGet(cell.Value)
        Url = "https://translate.google.pl/m?hl=" & translateFrom & "&sl=" & translateFrom & "&tl=" & translateTo & "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & getParam
        objHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        objHTTP.send ("")
        If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "div dir=""ltr""") > 0 Then
            trans = RegexExecute(objHTTP.responseText, "div[^""]*?""ltr"".*?>(.+?)</div>")
            cell.Value = Clean(trans)
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            'MsgBox ("Error")
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
 
'----Funciones Usadas----
Function ConvertToGet(val As String)
    val = Replace(val, " ", "+")
    val = Replace(val, vbNewLine, "+")
    val = Replace(val, "(", "%28")
    val = Replace(val, ")", "%29")
    ConvertToGet = val
End Function

Function Clean(val As String)
    val = Replace(val, "&quot;", """")
    val = Replace(val, "%2C", ",")
    val = Replace(val, "&#39;", "'")
    Clean = val
End Function

Public Function RegexExecute(str As String, reg As String, _
                             Optional matchIndex As Long, _
                             Optional subMatchIndex As Long) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = reg
    regex.Global = Not (matchIndex = 0 And subMatchIndex = 0) 'Para mayor Eficiencia.
    If regex.test(str) Then
        Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
        RegexExecute = matches(matchIndex).SubMatches(subMatchIndex)
        Exit Function
    End If
ErrHandl:
    RegexExecute = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you run it?

Comment: Right now nothing happens, because since it does not receive the info from google, it no longer proceeds to transcribe the information. makes an exit from the macro

Comment: Looks like maybe source code changed? The code does not throw any errors, but line `InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "div dir=""ltr""")` always return 0, so maybe you could replace the `Else` part  that says `On Error Resume Next` with `cell.Value = Clean(CStr(Split(Split(ObjHTTP.responsetext, "<div class=""result-container"">")(1), "</div>")(0)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like maybe source code changed? The code does not throw any errors, but line `InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "div dir=""ltr""")` always return 0, so maybe you could replace the `Else` part that says `On Error Resume Next` with:

```
cell.Value = Clean(CStr(Split(Split(ObjHTTP.responsetext, "<div class=""result-container"">")(1), "</div>")(0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may find a solution below. I hope it can be usefull.

```
Public Function GoogleTranslate(strInput As String, strFromSourceLanguage As String, strToTargetLanguage As String) As String
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim objHTML As Object
    Dim objDivs As Object, objDiv As Object
    Dim strTranslated As String

    ' send query to web page
    strURL = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=" & strFromSourceLanguage & _
        "&sl=" & strFromSourceLanguage & _
        "&tl=" & strToTargetLanguage & _
        "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & strInput

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 'late binding
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    'objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip;q=1.0", "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ""

    'MsgBox objHTTP.getResponseHeader("Content-Encoding")

    Dim httpresponse() As Byte
    httpresponse = objHTTP.responseBody
    'Mod_Inflate64.Inflate httpresponse
    'MsgBox StrConv(httpresponse, vbUnicode)
    'Debug.Print StrConv(httpresponse, vbUnicode)


    ' create an html document
    Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With objHTML
        .Open
        .Write objHTTP.responseText
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Z = objHTTP.responseText
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Y = InStr(Z, "result-container")
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  If Y > 0 Then
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --      Debug.Print Z
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  End If
        
        .Close
    End With
    
    '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Range("H1") = objHTTP.responsetext
    
    '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Set objDivsBody = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("body")
    Set objDivs = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("div")
    '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Set objDivs2 = objDivsBody(0).getElementsByTagName("div")
    '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Set objSpans = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("span")
    '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Set objSpans2 = objDivsBody(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
    
    
    '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Set objDivs2 = objHTML.getElementsByClassName("Q4iAWc")
    '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Set objDivs2 = objHTML.getElementsByClassName("JLqJ4b ChMk0b")
    
    '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  For Each objDiv In objDivsBody
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Z = objDiv.className
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Debug.Print Z
    '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Next objDiv
    
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Z = objDiv.className
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Debug.Print Z
        
        GoogleTranslate = GoogleTranslateRecursion(objDiv.ChildNodes)
        '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Debug.Print GoogleTranslate
        If GoogleTranslate <> "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If objDiv.className = "result-container" Then
            strTranslated = objDiv.innerText
            GoogleTranslate = strTranslated
            Exit For
        End If
        
    Next objDiv


    Set objHTML = Nothing
    Set objHTTP = Nothing

End Function


Function GoogleTranslateRecursion(pobjDivs As Object) As String
    Dim objDivs As Object, objDiv As Object
    Dim strTranslated As String
    GoogleTranslateRecursion = ""
    Set objDivs = pobjDivs
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        If objDiv.nodeName = "DIV" Then
            '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Z = objDiv.className
            '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Debug.Print Z
            strTranslated = GoogleTranslateRecursion(objDiv.ChildNodes)
            '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Debug.Print strTranslated
            If strTranslated <> "" Then
                GoogleTranslateRecursion = strTranslated
                Exit For
            End If
            
            If objDiv.className = "result-container" Then
                strTranslated = objDiv.innerText
                GoogleTranslateRecursion = strTranslated
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
    Next objDiv
End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).